# How to Access a Shared Google Calendar

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar, google-calendar

I have installed both `gnome-calendar` and `evolution` and can access my google calendar from both. My wife has shared her google calendar with me and I can see it on my calendar when I access it in a web browser. But I cannot find how to access my wife's shared calendar in either `gnome-calendar` or `evolution`. Can anyone help me access my wife's shared calendar in either of these apps? P.S.: this is all triggered by the fact that the `lightning` extension for `thunderbird` is no longer available, so I am trying to find a usable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to get `lightning` back in `thunderbird` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084059/latest-update-to-thunderbird-60-2-1-on-18-04-lightning-calendar-missing), so I don't need `gnome-calendar` or `evolution`!!!