# Which is the proper way to add Lightning calendar to Thunderbird (60+)?

Tags: apt, thunderbird, extension, lightning

A recent update of Thunderbird in Ubuntu (version 60.2.1) broke the Lightning calendar installed as add-on. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1084059/177068). Mozilla provides Lightning as bundled in the last versions, but Ubuntu (and Debian?) package do not, so now there is a mismatch between the Thunderbird version in the repositories and the add-on [provided by Mozilla](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) (5.4, only useful for Thunderbird 52).

One [suggested option](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084095/177068) is to search and install beta releases provided by Mozilla, but it looks as a workaround (future automatic updates are compromised). [Another](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084095/177068) is to delete the non-compatible Ligthning add-on and install a separate package (`xul-ext-lightning`) via apt, but it is not localised ([only available in English since at least 2010](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/545778)).

So, which is the proper "future-proof" way to install Lightning in Mozilla Thunderbird from now on (as intended by Ubuntu maintainers)?

1. Remove the internal add-on (`.xpi`) and install (`xul-ext-lightning`) [this package will be updated accordingly, together with Thunderbird and, eventually, localised]
2. Keep the Mozilla add-on until the mismatch with Thunderbird apt package is fixed
3. Remove the add-on and wait until a future Thunderbird apt package provides it integrated (as Mozilla bundles it for other platforms)

Comment: Option #1 is the fix.

Comment: @heynnema, option #1 is the fix if you are ok with the calendar in English. Given that `xul-ext-lightning` has not been fixed for i18n in the last 10 years, i would not hold my breath.

Comment: FairMiles, it's not at all "future-proof" (and risky versus possible critical bug-fixes) but another option is to [stick with an old version](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084406/16395)  until a fix is out.

Comment: @Rmano but you have to downgrade Thunderbird to use the old Lightning add-on. Extra note... TB 60.x disables a lot of existing, working, add-ons... sigh.

Comment: @heynnema yes it finally killed off my beloved FireTray. *heavy sigh*

Comment: @heynnema …and the so useful AttachExtraTools…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Mozilla provides Lightning as bundled in the last versions, but Ubuntu (and Debian?) package do not [...]

yes, both do not, but they provide lightning via a seperate package (`xul-ext-lightning` resp. `lightning`) in their repositories.
debian also provides lang-packs (`lightning-l10n-...`) for lightning and ubuntu does not. ***--> that's IMHO the main issue.***

> [...] so now there is a mismatch between the Thunderbird version in the repositories and the add-on provided by Mozilla [...]

there isn't really a "mismatch"... <s>for whatever reason mozilla simply does not provide lightning as add-on anymore.</s>
**EDIT:** have a look at the last section of this answer.

> (5.4, only useful for Thunderbird ≤52)

to avoid further confusion: [lightning 5.4 is only intended to work with thunderbird 52.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Calendar/Calendar_Versions#Stable_Releases)!

---

there is no "one and only right solution" because every workaround has it's pros & cons and depends on your preferences and skills... nonetheless i try to prioritize them:

1. (if you are ok with lightning in english) **the best is definitely to uninstall the lightning-addon and install lightning (`xul-ext-lightning`) via the repositories**:
   https://askubuntu.com/a/1084095/354350

**EDIT:** at the latest now jump to the last section of this answer.

2. if you need a different language, probably extracting the `{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}.xpi` (=lightning-addon) from [the official mozilla-releases](https://www.thunderbird.net/) (for every release) and installing into your profile via the addon-manager may be a reasonable workaround: 
   https://askubuntu.com/a/1084220/354350
3. you can also use [the archive provided by mozilla](https://www.thunderbird.net/) as a whole and update it on its own. - the packages (`thunderbird*` and `xul-ext-lightning`) from the repository should be uninstalled in this case.
4. <sub>if you are not afraid of potential bugs and do frequent backups of your data, installing the lightning-betas may also work for you:

   https://askubuntu.com/a/1084255/354350</sub>
5. <sub>if you are a skilled tinkerer, you can perhaps use the debian-packages or parts of it (eventually with auto-update), but it is very likely you will end in dependency hell!</sub>
6. if you are that skilled and seriously think about the last workaround, creating a PPA with lightnings lang-packs and providing them to all other users may be by far a better utilization of your time.
7. <sub>staying with an old thunderbird <60 for ages and using an already outdated lightning 5.4 is a really bad idea and should definitely be avoided!</sub>

---

there may be 2 future-proof real solutions for all users, <s>but i would not count on that we see even one of them soon</s>:

- ubuntu should finally fix it's packages and include lang-packs into/for the lightning-package (`xul-ext-lightning`)! ...as debian does.
- <s>mozilla could probably release lightning as add-on again and stop forcing users to fiddle around with separately downloaded betas and so on...</s>
  **EDIT:** since january 2019 (after nearly 2 years) **mozilla resp. thunderbird [(re)published lightning](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/lightning/)** >=6.2 (for thunderbird >=60) **as addon again!**

Comment: Lightning works fine from `xul-ext-lightning` after uninstalling the plugin (I use Thunderbird in English) but it breaks regional formats for the whole Thunderbird (so not only Lightning becomes affected by the lack of lang-packs). For example, I prefer 24-h format and I cannot get it with Lightning installed: [Thunderbird / Edit / Preferences / Advanced / Date and Time Formatting] just ignores my setting of whole system regional format (which is "English(Australia)") and shows the am-pm format…

Answer (score 0):

Fix for lightning & exchange calendar

Thunderbird did an automatic update this morning to version 60.2.1 and my calendar (this is provided by work MS office365 (exchange) disappeared. I had been living on legacy Lightning and EWS plugins which were now incompatible. So after some effort I am now back up and running - this is what I did:

1) start Thunderbird goto Tools -> Add-ons and remove the incompatible plugins (greyed out) then quit Thunderbird

2) added xul-ext-lighning from repositories using Synaptic

3) restarted Thunderbird open Calendar pane, under the drop-down menu on right of tool bar I found an option to unsubscribe to the now defunct 'Exchange' calendar (I am not sure this is necessary but this is what I did) and I think you could do this directly from the Events and Tasks tab

4) goto Tools -> Add-ons and download and install the TbSync plugin, restart Thunderbird

5) Under the Edit tab select the new entry 'Synchronization Settings (TbSync)'; bottom left  click button 'Account actions' -> '+ New account'; fill in details user name, password and exchange server (I had to use 'custom' option as TbSync could not automatically discover the work 365 server address); after a couple of minutes everything synced and calendar and address book were all correctly re-established.

One question I have is I am not sure how to set TbSync to automatically resynchronise or even if this is a problem.

Addendum - Due to change in TbSync, you now need to also download the Exchange Active Sync (EAS) plugin as well